# AngularJS reference input elements on ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I know this is not a good question, but i can't seem to find the answer, i cannot use a form, i have a ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows" data-target="#stockitem_{{ '{{row.id}} '}}">
    <td>{{ '{{row.id}} '}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{ '{{row.name}} '}}"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="{{ '{{row.stock_count}}' }}"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="{{ '{{row.sku}}' }}"></td>
    <td>{{ '{{row.user.company}}' }}</td>
    <td class="update"><button type="submit" ng-click="updateStockItem()" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Opdater</button></td>
    <td class="delete"><button type="submit" ng-click="deleteStockItem(row.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Slet</button></td>
</tr>
```

What would be the best way to reference the input elements on updateStockItem?

I cannot use a form with ng-submit, i cannot use a variable ng-model names for some reason, such as.

```
ng-model="stockitem.{{ '{{ row.id}}' }}.name"
```

I would prefer not to use JQuery to select them from the ID, it is no problem for the delete action, since i just need the ID, but i would like to have the input values inside $scope, when updateStockItem is click.

The double brackets are due to twig btw.

Comment: Explain me the sense of double brackets it looks non sense to me? what do you would?

Comment: It is required when using the twig template engine, a symfony2 component, this is not the issue :-)

Comment: Take $index as `updateStockItem` parameter and inside control you refear to this value by `$scope.rows[ix]` but this still seems a bad approach, since not having ng-model this value are not two-way-bounded, so....

Comment: are you saying that you are using another framework that uses `{{ }}`, so you are trying to wrap the angular expressions inside that?  I can't work out how you would know what the expression angular is really seeing would be.

Comment: also, this doesn't really make sense, in `stockitem.{{ '{{ row.id}}' }}.name`, are you trying to extract the `row.id` on the server (in twig) and then dynamically inject it into the expression client side?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense out of what those double tags really mean, and I'm at a loss. angular expressions aren't strings, so `'{{row.id}}'` by itself doesn't make sense.  You might consider using the `$interpolateProvider` in angular to change your symbols to something like `[[ ]]` so that it's a bit easier to understand.

Comment: also `ng-model` doesn't need to be interpolated, so instead of `<input type="text" value="{{ '{{row.name}} '}}">`, you should be able to use `<input type="text" ng-model="row.name">`

Comment: with all the values two way bound, then you could just call `ng-click="updateStockItem(row)"` and have the row that needs to be persisted in your function.

Comment: If you want access html element then you can create link function in directive.app.directive('ngClick', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.onClick = function() {
                console.log('onClick');
            };
        }
    };
});  but I agree with Claies ng-click="updateStockItem(row)".you can access all value of row in controller or directive.